# laravel 5.2 controller show method not showing $id

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have Laravel 5.2 and nginx server. When I try to access any page it shows a 500 error. I am trying to echo `$id` in the `show` method but it is redirecting to nginx error.

Comment: Have a look at `storage/logs/laravel.log` and find out what the error is.

Comment: i saw the log there was no error appears. It works fine in my local system.

Comment: Have a look at your nginx logs too.

Comment: when i enter - public/vendors/122.  Vendorcontroleer show($id) { echo $id;} error is  throwing /vendors/[object%20Object]